# Error installing old packages in R

Tags: r, gcc, rstudio, tm

I'm trying to install a 0.6-2 version of the tm library. I've downloaded the tar.gz file from the [archive](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/tm/) and in RStudio selected Tools -> Archive -> Package Archive File to install it.

However, I'm getting the following error. Can someone help me fix this please:

> - installing *source* package 'tm' ...
>     ** package 'tm' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>     ** libs
>
> *** arch - i386
>   c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c copy.c -o copy.o
>   c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc: not found
>   make: *** [copy.o] Error 127
>
> Warning: running command 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.2/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.2/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="tm.dll" OBJECTS="copy.o"' had status 2
>   ERROR: compilation failed for package 'tm'
>   * removing 'C:/Users/608447283/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/tm'
>
> Warning in install.packages :
>     running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\608447283\Documents\R\win-library\3.3" "C:/Users/608447283/desktop/tm_0.6-2.tar.gz"' had status 1
>
> Warning in install.packages :
>     installation of package ‘C:/Users/608447283/desktop/tm_0.6-2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should install Rtools which contains resources needed to build packages in R under Microsoft Windows :

https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

After installing, you should see it under your PATH variable:

```
Sys.getenv("PATH")
```

Comment: I have Rtools already installed but I've only installed the 64 bit version not 32 bit. That caused the issue. Your answer helped me look at it properly. Thank you.

Comment: @np. If the answer was helpful, please uptick. Thanks.