# How can I run a program, that uses the openxlsx package, from another computer using shinyapps.io?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, openxls

What happened is this:

I built a program using Shiny. But in this program, I am also using openxlsx in order to print my results in an excel file using write.xlsx(). So at the very top of my server.R file, I wrote this piece of code:

```
Sys.setenv("R_ZIPCMD" = "C:/Rtools/bin/zip.exe")

library(openxlsx)
```

When I run it in my computer, it worked just fine. But when I deployed it into the cloud (using shinyapps.io) and run it in another computer (using a Chrome), I got this error:

```
*Error: zipping up workbook failed. Please make sure Rtools is installed or a zip application is available to R. Try installr:: install.rtools() on Windows.*
```

Comment: when I use your app (the link your provided further below) I get this: ERROR: object 'Fec.Emision.Poliza' not found

Comment: Hello MLavoie, this is because it only works with an specific csv file I recieve each month from the company I work for. I wrote the link for him to understand that I was talking about a web app. It seems he delete his answer...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error installing old packages in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42565317/error-installing-old-packages-in-r)